# Spring security configuration error: beans have the same 'order' value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Web Application in which i am implementing spring security my `spring-security.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- ENABLE HTTP SECURITY -->
    <http auto-config="false" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.html">

        <!-- INTERCEPT URL FOR RESOURCES ACCESS -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/" access="hasRole('ADMIN_ROLE')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/" access="hasRole('USER_ROLE')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

        <!-- CUSTOME FILTER -->
        <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="AuthFilter" />

        <!-- SESSION MANAGEMENT CONFIG -->
        <session-management
            session-authentication-strategy-ref="session-management" />

        <!-- FORM LOGIN CONFIG -->
        <form-login login-page="/loginForm"
            authentication-failure-url="/error.html" default-target-url="/welcome.html" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/loggedout.html"
            invalidate-session="true" />
    </http>
    <!-- SERVICES  -->
    <beans:bean id="customEncoder" class="com.rep.security.CustomPasswordEncoder"></beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="customUserService" class="com.rep.security.CustomUserDetailService"></beans:bean>

    <!-- AUTHENICATION MANAGER CONFIG -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserService">
            <password-encoder ref="customEncoder"></password-encoder>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- CONCURRENCY FILEER CONFIG -->
    <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/timeout.html" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="AuthFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy"
            ref="session-management" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="session-management"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry"
            ref="sessionRegistry" />
        <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
</beans:beans>
```

At the time of running the application on jboss i am facing this error

```
15:40:02,470 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Filter beans '<AuthFilter>' and 'Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null' have the same 'order' value. When using custom filters, please make sure the positions do not conflict with default filters. Alternatively you can disable the default filters by removing the corresponding child elements from <http> and avoiding the use of <http auto-config='true'>.
```

Can any one tell me what is problem configuration i am following [Spring Doc ioc] for [session management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.6.RELEASE/reference/session-mgmt.html)

Answer (score 9):

You should read [4.3.6. Adding in Your Own Filters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-custom-filters) and [Table 1. Standard Filter Aliases and Ordering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#filter-stack)

> If you’ve used Spring Security before, you’ll know that the framework
> maintains a chain of filters in order to apply its services.

> The order of the filters is always strictly enforced when using the
> namespace. When the application context is being created, the filter
> beans are sorted by the namespace handling code and the standard
> Spring Security filters each have an alias in the namespace and a
> well-known position.

Your `<form-login>` is using a filter with alias `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER`. And also you are adding another filter with the same position (`position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="AuthFilter"`). So you're getting the error message

> Filter beans `<AuthFilter>` and `Root bean: class [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter]` have the same `order` value

So I think you need to change the position if you want the both:

```
<custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="AuthFilter" />
```

or

```
<custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="AuthFilter" />
```

Comment: Which is interesting since they provide a parameter called "position" supposedly replacing a default filter. Yet this doesn't seem to work, even in current versions of the library.

Answer (score 1):

From the spring security docs, section B1.5. [The Security Namespace](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-namespace.html):

> <form-login> element - Used to add an
>   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to the filter stack.

Basically <form-login> element will add UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter and I think it conflicts with the filter you define in "AuthFilter" bean.

Comment: But my AuthFilter is also `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` implementation

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe that you will either have to remove form-login element and then configure your AuthFilter manually to do what form-login configuration element does (take a look at the documentation url to see what it does) or remove your custom AuthFilter and configure what you want to achieve using Spring Security Namespace xml elements (if possible).